# Install Script MSI : How to install the product in Current Users Home directory when running the exe as administrator?

Tags: installation, admin, installshield, installscript, installscript-msi

I have a msi which is created from an IS Installscript msi project , as the product requires elevated permissions it should be running as administrator . Everything is fine , but now the product is getting installed on Admins home rather than the users home directory.

when i am using GetEnvVar(USERPROFILE,svUserProfile) , i am getting admins home directory rather than the current logged in user directory.

Any help is appreciated in solving this.

Comment: Can you find a way to setting the [ALLUSER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367559(v=vs.85).aspx) property to `1` in the final MSI?

Comment: I tried setting ALLUSER to 1 from install shield property editor but it didnt work.